# Starting a web application using Express and Ember

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ember.js

I want to write a simple CMS using Node.js (with Express) and Ember.js. I am totally new to Ember.js, but I am familiar with Angular. I see Ember.js is very close to Angular because it uses a CLI with "ember serve" command to run the client app. But in Node.js I also have to start the server using "npm start". As any CMS, there is a "public" part (the site pages) served by Express using Handlebars and an "admin" part (the reserved area, with administrative pages) that is the web app wrote in Ember.js. Is there a way to have both client and server routes from a single base domain and port (i.e. http://localhost:3000/ for public pages and http://localhost:3000/admin/ for the admin pages)? And there is a way to start the whole project with a single command, instead of typing "npm start" for the server and "ember serve" for the client? Maybe the only way is to render Ember.js templates server-side with Fastboot? I am very confused about the development of a web app like this.

Comment: In React you can build project (npm run-script build for react create app) and after thay you will upload files to your node.js folder like "public" and with the help of express (express static) you can send files to peoples (response on request of files). You should start only express (needn`t server for front-end, express will send files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ember serve` is starting a *development* server. You should not run this in production. Just build the application using `ember build --prod` and serve it as you want.

To forward requests to your api in development, use `proxy` option of `ember serve`. E.g.  `ember serve --proxy http://127.0.0.1:3000`. This will startup ember development server (providing live reload at file changes) at port 4200 and forward api requests to port `3000` on `127.0.0.1`.

If this is not enough for you (talking about *development* environment only), you could always run a nginx proxy providing that magic...

Do not forget to adjust [`rootURL` configuration](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/#toc_specifying-a-root-url) of your ember app, if not serving from webroot.